# What did Bullitt see or think of when he went back to the hotel where his partner and the mobster were shot?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, bullitt

Fairly early in the movie *Bullitt* Steve McQueen returns to the hotel scene where his partner and the mobster were holed up and shot by 2 mob hitmen.

He opens the hotel door, now a crime scene, and looks around.  For one thing, I noticed he focused on the window of the room.

What’s the significance of this scene?  What was Bullitt looking for? And what, if anything, did he notice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It's unclear

The [**shooting script**](https://edoc.site/bullitt-1968-shooting-script-pdf-free.html) does not indicate any special interest in  the windows when Bullitt revisits the hotel room...

> Bullitt comes in, eyes it carefully, takes in: the marks showing where the bodies were found, the powdered finger-prints, the powder on the blood splotches on the floor, bed,and wall behind the bed. The SNARL of traffic underscores the silence in the room. Bullitt ponders, looks at the unbroken chain. He closes the door, slides the chain into the slot, then opens the door. The chain holds, an effective barrier. Slowly, giving this aspect much thought, Bullitt closes the door, undoes the chain, drops it. It hits the door jamb with a metallic CLINK, comes to rest. Worried,unable to fathom it,  Bullitt starts out, closing the door behind him.

However, Bullitt had already expressed concern over the choice of hotel room and the visibility of the room from outside telling Rennick to...

> Stay away from the windows, that's why.

So it's possible that Bullitt was reconsidering HOW the killers came to find the victim and whether it's possible they spotted him from outside.

Comment: Yes, I think your very last paragraph is probably the case.  I would add to it ...”and after looking at the window, Bullitt ruled it out”.

Comment: I did notice, after viewing the movie, that when entering the crime scene the camera focuses on Bullitt, the crime scene drawing, the bed and a window and then finally a  window (again) for a longer second time.  Which is why I was curious about the window.